# Php-sql result in joomla displayed in question marks

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple sql query, in a joomla php server, rs forms. The result contains Greek characters. However, the result is displayed in question marks.

```
$sql = "SELECT `FieldValue` FROM `table` where `FieldName` = 'age' and `SubmissionId` =   ".$submissionId."
";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

{ echo
     $row["FieldValue"] ; 
}
```

Result:

??? 20 ????
(question marks should be Greek letters)

I tried using convert as utf8, and it did not work. What else can i do?

```
  $sql = "SELECT CONVERT(`FieldValue` USING utf8) as `FieldValue`
  FROM `table` where `FieldName` = 'age' and `SubmissionId` =   ".$submissionId."";
```

Comment: try putting charset=utf8 in your connection

Comment: I dont think greek letters are part of UTF8

Comment: make sure that in HTML head is also using UTF8 encoding

Comment: Tried header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
did not change anything. No html, used, just php.